# Pass data from controller to controller safely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I have 2 controllers: a  `Subscriptions` controller and a `PaypalExplress` controller. First handles all subsription data, second handles paypal transactions.

The problem is a have to path somehow a price amount (`@subscription.price`) from `Subscriptions` to paypal controller. I thought about `session[]` and `params[]` hashes, but I assume it's not a secure way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You can encrypt and decrypt your session parameter.

```
Encode(Session["price"].ToString());



        public string Encode(string encodeMe)
        {
            byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodeMe);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
        }

        public static string Decode(string decodeMe)
        {
            byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(decodeMe);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
        }
```

Comment: Encoding may be a good idea, but it looks like a C# code, not Ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `@subscription` not an instanced model? If you have a row in a database just redirect to the appropriate URL passing along the subscription ID and retrieve the data on the other side.

You need to understand [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and it wouldn't hurt to read some [getting started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guides on the MVC principle.

Comment: the problem is @subscription record is not saved when redirecting to paypal controller, so it doesn't have an id. Also user can write another id to the url, and paypal transaction will work with wrong subscription.